# Using Static Methods to handle a large list of SharedPrefs... Is this a good idea?

Tags: android

I am writing a game for Android that requires a ton of simple data (stats, map locations etc...) to be stored in SharedPreferences.

To simplify and streamline this process I created a Settings class that uses static set and get methods for all the sharedprefs. Then I simply call settings.getXYZ() from anywhere else in the app.

Lately I have read that using static methods in Android is a bad idea in the long run. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: "static methods in Android is a bad idea" - where did you read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you have a set of static methods in a public class designed to get and set any preferences as properties.

This is how I have it setup in my apps, and it works great!  As long as you treat them as static objects, you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

For a big set of values to be stored I suggest you to use a sqlite db instead of sharedpreferences. It is easier to manage and not difficult to learn to use it.

Comment: What advantage would this provide me over SharedPrefs? I do not need to do any sorting of the data at all whatsoever and most of the data is small Strings and Integers.

Comment: I'm using sharedpreferences for 5-6 variables and I found a boring job to manage/edit/change/load strings in this manner. Well, it depends about personal experiences and knowledges but I think the use of a light db as sqlite is more friendly.

Comment: SharedPreferences is an SQLite DB, it is just managed by Android :)